# Exception: missing ) after for-loop control

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I received the above exception when running the code.

```
// this function assumes the CSV has no fields with commas,
// and strips out all the double quotes


function parseCsvResponse(csvString) {
    var retArray = [];

    var strLines = csvString.split(/\n/g);
    var strLineLen = strLines.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < strLineLen; i++) {
        var line = strLines[i];
        if (line != '') {
            retArray.push(line.replace(/"/g, "").split(/,/));
        }
    }

    return retArray;
}

function populateSheetWithCSV(sheet, csvUrl, user, pw) {

    // request the CSV!
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl, {
        headers: {
            // use basic auth
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)
        }
    });
```

```
// parse the response as a CSV
var csvContent = parseCsvResponse(resp.getContentText());

// clear everything in the sheet
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();

// set the values in the sheet (as efficiently as we know how)
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvContent.length /* rows */, csvContent[0].length /* columns */).setValues(csvContent);
```

}

Comment: Quote characters should come in pairs.

Comment: By the way, there's the `Utilities.parseCsv` function. You don't need to develop it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This line looks like the culprit, as the commenter suggested:

`retArray.push(line.replace(/"/g, "").split(/,/));`

You've got an open double quotation pair.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it is because of this.

```
/"/g
```

You can put this in quotes. Something like this:

```
var myregexp =new RegExp('"','g');
```

Issue: Almost the same. Star it?

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=419